# Is there an XSD validator for Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xsd

I need to validate XML in a node.js application.I have found [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xsd-schema-validator), but it's basically a java plugin, and despite the excellent pun making opportunities, I would prefer not to use Java in my JavaScript. So is there a native node module that can validate XML based on an XSD schema? (1.1 compatibility very much preferred)

Comment: http://syssgx.github.io/xml.js/ was the first match in a Google Search for "Javascript XSD Validator"

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=xsd ... look for one with lots of downloads and well maintained

Answer (score 3):

there have neen some new developments since you originally asked:

- https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs provides a javascript wrapper for libxml, though it does require some building/binding using node-gyp.
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmllint is basically an Emscripten javascript port of libxml2's xmllint code.
- another out-of-the-box solution to consider is translating the XSD to a JSON schema, translating the XML to JSON, and then running JSON validation. Though this has more steps and can be more error prone.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[cxml](https://github.com/charto/cxml) is not a complete validator (especially restrictions are unsupported) but it can parse XML to JSON dropping elements and attributes that the schema doesn't define, and convert everything to correct data types.

Answer (score 0):

found 
 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxml-xsd
 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xsd-schema-validator

Both not much stared yet :/

Comment: the xsd-schema-validator assumes java's present so thats a heads up for anyone if its a deal breaker.